# VPCIdNotSpecified: No default VPC for this user error when doing terraform apply

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Terraform newbie here.

I am using the `Terraform in Action` book [here](https://livebook.manning.com/book/terraform-in-action/chapter-1/77). When I run the `terraform apply`, I get a `VPCIdNotSpecified: No default VPC for this user. GroupName is only supported for EC2-Classic and default VPC` error. I have installed both the AWS CLI and configured my AWS credentials using `aws configure`. My AWS credentials are present in `%UserProfile%\.aws\credentials` file.

What am I missing?

**main.tf**

```
provider "aws" {
    region = "us-west-2"
}
resource "aws_instance" "helloworld" {
    ami = "ami-09dd2e08d601bff67"
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
    tags = {
        Name = "HelloWorld"
    }
}
```

**Error stackTrace:**

```
aws_instance.helloworld: Creating...
╷
│ Error: Error launching source instance: VPCIdNotSpecified: No default VPC for this user. GroupName is only supported for EC2-Classic and default VPC.
│       status code: 400, request id: 1e0911db-300b-4c00-aea1-dad588bbe40e
│
│   with aws_instance.helloworld,
│   on main.tf line 4, in resource "aws_instance" "helloworld":
│    4: resource "aws_instance" "helloworld" {
│
```

Answer (score 2):

it seems like you don't have a default VPC in the `us-west-2` region.

Since you have mentioned you are just starting off with Terraform; I would highly recommend, referring to [official Terraform documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/) when you want to use a particular resource/module/provider.

In this case, for [Resource: aws_instance](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance), you can see what all attributes are supported.

If I were you I would first check if there's a default VPC in the aforementioned region. It's highly likely there's none. If I know the VPC subnet ID then I would simply pass on that value to the [subnet_id](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance#subnet_id) attribute and Terraform will ensure that my instance will come up in the correct network.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to create default vpc
[image]